# C# Exp cannot get result

Tags: c#

When I using Math.Exp() in C# I have some questions?This code is about Kernel density estimation, and I don't have any knowledge about kernel density estimation. So I look up some wiki and some paper.

I try to write it by C#. The problem is when "distance" is getting higher the result is become 0. It's confuse me and I cannot find any other way to get the right result.

```
disExp = Math.Pow(Math.E, -(distance / 2 * Math.Pow(h, 2)));
```

So, can any one help me to get the solution? Or give me some idea about Kernel density estimation on C#. Sorry for poor English.

Comment: This should make sense from a purely mathematical perspective. Raising any number to a number that is tending towards negative infinity will result in a number that tends towards zero. So as `distance` gets larger in your expression the result will quickly become `0`.

Comment: Thank you, I know it will tend to be 0, but is there any solution to get the right value ?

Comment: I think if you need any further help then you need to post all of the relevant code and you need to post a link to a reference on how the KDE is meant to be computed. Please don't make this a research project for us.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public static double[,] KernelDensityEstimation(double[] data, double sigma, int nsteps)
    {
        // probability density function (PDF) signal analysis
        // Works like ksdensity in mathlab. 
        // KDE performs kernel density estimation (KDE)on one - dimensional data
        // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation

        // Input:   -data: input data, one-dimensional
        //          -sigma: bandwidth(sometimes called "h")
        //          -nsteps: optional number of abscis points.If nsteps is an
        //          array, the abscis points will be taken directly from it. (default 100)
        // Output:  -x: equispaced abscis points
        //          -y: estimates of p(x)

        // This function is part of the Kernel Methods Toolbox(KMBOX) for MATLAB. 
        // http://sourceforge.net/p/kmbox
        // Converted to C# code by ksandric

        double[,] result = new double[nsteps, 2];
        double[] x = new double[nsteps], y = new double[nsteps];

        double MAX = Double.MinValue, MIN = Double.MaxValue;
        int N = data.Length; // number of data points

        // Find MIN MAX values in data
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            if (MAX < data[i])
            {
                MAX = data[i];
            }
            if (MIN > data[i])
            {
                MIN = data[i];
            }
        }

        // Like MATLAB linspace(MIN, MAX, nsteps);
        x[0] = MIN;
        for (int i = 1; i < nsteps; i++)
        {
            x[i] = x[i - 1] + ((MAX - MIN) / nsteps);
        }

        // kernel density estimation
        double c = 1.0 / (Math.Sqrt(2 * Math.PI * sigma * sigma));
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < nsteps; j++)
            {
                y[j] = y[j] + 1.0 / N * c * Math.Exp(-(data[i] - x[j]) * (data[i] - x[j]) / (2 * sigma * sigma));
            }
        }

        // compilation of the X,Y to result. Good for creating plot(x, y)
        for (int i = 0; i < nsteps; i++)
        {
            result[i, 0] = x[i];
            result[i, 1] = y[i];
        }
        return result;
    }
```

[kernel density estimation C#](https://gist.github.com/ksandric/e91860143f1dd378645c01d518ddf013)

[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0f7e7.jpg)

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation to your answer. Why is your code working, what was the OP doing wrong and etc